# Array of object with variables x and y of type double when one equals 1.0000 does not work and gives no error

Tags: c++

planevector.cpp file

```
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class planeVector
{
    double x;
    double y;
    public:
        planeVector(int x = 0,int y = 0)
        {
            (*this).x = x;
            (*this).y = y;
        }

        ~planeVector()
        {
            delete &x;
            delete &y;
        }

        void operator+=(planeVector vec)
        {
            this->x+=vec.x;
            this->y+=vec.y;
        }

        void operator-=(planeVector vec)
        {
            this->x-=vec.x;
            this->y-=vec.y;
        }

        void operator*=(double num)
        {
            (*this).x*=num;
            (*this).y*=num;
        }

        void operator/=(double num)
        {
            (*this).x/=num;
            (*this).y/=num;
        }

        planeVector operator+(planeVector vec)
        {
            return planeVector((*this).x+vec.x,(*this).y+vec.y);
        }

        planeVector operator-(planeVector vec)
        {
            return planeVector((*this).x-vec.x,(*this).y-vec.y);
        }

        planeVector operator/(double num)
        {
            return planeVector((*this).x/num,(*this).y/num);
        }

        planeVector operator*(double num)
        {
            return planeVector((*this).x*num,(*this).y*num);
        }
        void normalize()
        {
            (*this)/=(*this).mag();
        }

        double mag()
        {
            return pow(this->x*this->x+this->y*this->y,0.5); 
        }

        operator std::string const()
        {
            return "("+ std::to_string(this->x)+", "+std::to_string(this->y)+")";   
        }
};
```

main.cpp file

```
#include "string"
#include "iostream"
#include "./planevector.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    planeVector y[17];
    for(int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
    {
        y[i] = planeVector(6,1);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
    {
        cout << std::string(y[i]) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

whenever I try to create more than one planeVector object with values x = /*some number*/ and y = 1
it just doesn't work, and there's no error that's given, it just ends. it compiles succesfully and while it runs it stops whenever it reaches the for loop unless the values are not 1.

changing the data types to int or long works, while float and double do not work, however I want it to use double.

Comment: Not really related to your reported problem but the `delete &x;` and `delete &y;` lines in the destructor are just plain wrong. You didn't create them with `new` so don't attempt to free them with `delete`.

Comment: ... or maybe it *is* (related to) your problem. Every time that destructor is called, you'll get Undefined Behaviour, which can manifest as a crash.

Comment: ... yeah, just remove those two `delete` lines and try again.

Comment: Also, why are the parameters for your c'tor `int` types? It would make more sense to have those as `double`, surely.

Comment: @AdrianMole yes it does make more sense, the reason why its that way is because I was trying to problem solve by changing the types to see if that would work. and I guess I must have missed that while pasting it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that immediately strikes me as odd is your destructor. `x` and `y` weren't allocated with `new`, so deleting them is undefined behavior, meaning anything can happen (most likely a crash). You shouldn't have to call `delete` directly in 99% of C++ code.

Try removing the destructor and see what happens.

Comment: actually as a matter of fact that was the problem.
by changing it so the doubles were allocated with new, it worked. thank you

Comment: I wouldn't recommend allocating them with new at all. If you are new to c++, I highly suggest familiarizing yourself with the heap and the stack, and the differences between the two.

Comment: Yes, although you didn't realise it when you wrote the answer, the destructor will cause the problem.   Other code is passing instances of `planeVector` *by value* as function arguments which involves (1) creating a temporary to pass to the function (2) destructing that temporary after calling the function.      Repeatedly calling `delete` on pointers not resulting from a corresponding `new` can *easily* trash program memory.